# MySQL: how to merge similar rows together?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have about 100k rows in a table where I'm trying to combine same events with different event ids together. There are two types of event ids available: *[0-9A-F]{16}* and *^[0-9]{6,7}$*

I'm doing the matching based on event name, event date and event location.

So far the best way I came up with was to do and inner join, but it's way too slow:

```
SELECT  mto.eventID, mti.eventID, mto.eventName, mti.eventName, mto.venueName, mti.venueName
    FROM eventdiscovery mto
    INNER JOIN eventdiscovery mti ON
    mti.cityState = mto.cityState and mti.eventDate = mto.eventDate and mti.venueName = mto.venueName
    and mti.eventName = mto.eventName
    and ((mto.eventID REGEXP '[0-9A-F]{16}' and mti.eventID REGEXP '^[0-9]{6,7}$') or (mto.eventID REGEXP '^[0-9]{6,7}$' and mti.eventID REGEXP '[0-9A-F]{16}'))
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry dont have your data here.. there's a lot of options if i have a sample data from you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query wants an index on:  `event_discovery(cityState, eventDate, venueName, eventName, eventId)`.

The regular expression match does have overhead but with the right index, it might be fast enough.